# Вывести статью по названию в Opencart

Tags: php, opencart, cms

Там в описание, есть таблицы. Они прописаны не в самом описание, а созданы через Статьи, и подгружаются туда через - [таблица 1] , [таблица 2] и т.п.

Пример на новом - http://new1.sparkavto.ru/katalog-tovarov/shtatnye-kamery-zadnego-vida/dodge_camera/spark-d1
Пример на старом - https://sparkavto.ru/dodge_camera/spark-d1

А сами таблицы находятся тут - https://prnt.sc/tdboxm

Как реализовать это, посоветуйте статью или урок